# Is the date on the oil sticker very important?

Tags: maintenance, scheduled-maintenance, preventive-maintenance

I'm trying to balance coronavirus with following my oil sticker. We are mostly staying at home and not driving much to avoid coronavirus, so our mileage is still slightly under the mileage on the sticker.  The dates of our 2 cars are 1/2020 and 2/2020. So I am wondering if I can wait over a year from that date (since we probably won't get a vaccine until early next year) or if that hurts the car. We do try to switch off driving them whenever we grocery shopping.

Thanks!

Comment: My two cents: the oil does not really expire. I'm sure there are some minuscule chemical reactions going on while it's sitting in your oil pan, but it's nothing to be concerned about. I always just go by the mileage driven - and I drive high mileage vehicles.

Comment: You are safe doing what you are doing, if that makes sense. Oil change date or mileage is not critical, you can go past a 1000 miles and be safe.